# Set nested master page's master

Tags: c#-4.0, webforms

OK I've got a master page and a nested master page that inherits that master.

All pages implement the nested master page:

```
MasterPage
     --> NestedMaster
            --> Page1
            --> Page2
            --> etc.
```

So I need to set the **top level** master page dynamically. 2 sites with completly differing layouts in the header and the header only.

How can I control this in code? Looked at the event hierachy but this just says you can only set the master page at **page level**, I've got thousands of pages! **This is not practcal**.

I want to make a single change at the *NestedMaster* page level and that level only. Can this be done?

I've tried:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    this.MasterPageFile = getMasterPath();
    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

but I just get:

> The 'MasterPageFile' property can only be set in or before the
>   'Page_PreInit' event.

The master page has no `PreInit` event, annoyingly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having done a bit more googling I realise this isn't possible becuase the base class is the `Page` and this is the first thing called and therefore the only place you can specify the PreInit. God I hate webforms.

That said I think I've got a solution from http://odetocode.com/Articles/450.aspx. Basically produce a custom HTTPModule:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

public class MasterPageModule : IHttpModule
{  
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(context_PreRequestHandlerExecute);
    }

    void context_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
        if (page != null)
        {
            page.PreInit +=new EventHandler(page_PreInit);
        }
    }

    void page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page page = sender as Page;
        if (page != null)
        {
            page.MasterPageFile = "~/Master1.master";
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```